# Menu does not show

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm on my way to build my first Wordpress theme. Now I hit a problem with my menu. It is shown in the source code, but not on the [website](http://harnisch.pressebuero-schiel.de/).

My code in the functions.php

```
function register_theme_menus() {

register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary-menu'  => __( 'Primary Menu' )         
    )
);

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus' );
```

My code in the header-php

```
<?php 

  $defaults = array(
    'container' => false,
    'theme_location'  => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class'  => 'no-bullet'
  );

  wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

What's wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Add your `<nav>`   tag below the `h1` tag
Use the below Jquery javascript code, I just tested localy your index page and worked fine for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".nav-toggle").click(function(event) {
    jQuery("nav").toggle('in');
});
</script>
```

Please change your toggle code because `href=""` is empty you must provide a `#`

```
<a class="nav-toggle" href=""><span></span>Menu</a>
```

with

```
<a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span>Menu</a>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9cyb8s9o/)

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. BUT: Every click on that nav button seems to ignite a page reload. So the menu disappears again a second later. Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Edited my answer please try it but I found also some wrong apostrophes in your code some has " and some other are with '

Answer (score 1):

Your Menu is registered as of what it shows in view-source but your toggle button is not working, as your toggle button is not linked with the menu so it just refreshed the page.

Your toggle button link is like this:

```
<a href="" class="nav-toggle"><span></span>Menu</a>
```

So the href link for toggle button is blank.

Check following link to know how toggle button works:

https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz

Answer (score 1):

Try this page:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/menu-not-appearing

I also found this page that mentions some context: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

```
 wp-includes/nav-menu.php
```

There seems to be a few pages coming into play, so you might be just missing quick edit. I have a good feeling about that first URL though. It mentions fix for very similar if not same issue.